# How to use file_exists function for a directory outside of current folder?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check whether an image file (.jpg) exists using `file_exists` for a directory which is outside of the current file directory.

**Diagram of file system**

```
Image Directory
Websites -> GetaShoe -> 190 -> Image file 
websites/WEBSITE1/190/123.jpg

Current Directory
Websites -> Shoesgb -> current directory
websites/WEBSITE2/currentpage.php
```

So how would I check whether a file exists within the image directory when using `file_exists` within the current directory?

I've tried the following:

```
<?php

     $filename = '/GetAShoe/190/123.jpg';

     if (file_exists($filename)) { echo 'Found'; } else { echo 'Not Found'; }

?>
```

This doesn't work as no images are found at all within a directory of 1000's images.

Can anybody advise on the correct way to refer to an external file path?

Thanks

Comment: `/GetAShoe` is looking for the equivalent of `C:\GetAShoe`. You probably want something more like `../GetAShoe`. PHP doesn't know anything about and couldn't care less about your site's document root. It just sees the server's filesystem.

Comment: / on a linux system is the root folder, ./ is the current folder and ../ is one folder above the current folder. You should either use the full path (/home/user/www/somedir/190/123.jpg), or a relative root, like @MarcB posted

Comment: @JimL - thanks for the tip regarding the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the use the ABSOLUTE file path, which I found using `__FILE__`

So the correct path was :

```
<?php 

$filename = "/root/26/987654321/htdocs/websites/WEBSITE/190/$info[product_id].jpg"; 

if (file_exists($filename)) { echo 'Found'; } else { echo 'Not Found'; }

?>
```

Note actual file path has been altered for security reasons, the path provided above is for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative pathname to the image directory. `/` starts you at your computer root. As Marc said: `../GetAShoe` will probably work.

Comment: @aphextwix relative paths are usually preferred. I would suggest trying to check __DIR__ (echo or dump) to see if you are in the dir you think you are. You might have to go up two directories instead of just one.